# The minimal number with a given number of divisors

Tags: number-theory

My question comes here https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2005.04.004. Let $A(n)$ which assigns to each number $n$ the smallest number with exactly $n$ divisors. Is it true that $A(n)<A(n+1)$?

Comment: Is not the smallest number with $n$ divisors $2^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Phicar:  It is, if $n$ is prime.  The smallest number with $4$ divisors is $6$

Comment: @RossMillikan I see, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The smallest number with exactly $5$ divisors is $2^4=16$.  The smallest with $6$ divisors is $12$.  The numbers are given in [OEIS A005179](http://oeis.org/A005179) and you can see many decreases.  It starts
$$1, 2, 4, 6, 16, 12, 64, 24, 36, 48, 1024, 60, 4096, 192, 144, 120, 65536, 180$$
The smallest number with $p$ divisors, for $p$ prime, is $2^{p-1}$  Often the next number will be smaller.